# Why do wmaker icons shrink?

Tags: icons, window-maker

I find myself spending too much time getting the wmakers icons right. When I start an application from the commandline I get an Icon, which I can attach to the dock or the clip. Good.

However, when the application is not running, the icon shrinks to about half the size. The tile keeps its original size (48x48) but the image in it gets smaller. This small image does not look good.

I can work around this, by explicitly specifying an icon (rightClick -> settings). But it just takes too much time to browse through all the available icons (unless there is a fast way I am not aware of). I would be happy if wmaker just kept the icon it originally displayed.

Seems like I do not fully understand, how wmaker can display an icon of a running application just fine, but sometimes requires configuration, when the application is not running.

So why do wmaker icons shrink and what can be done to avoid spending too much time in getting the icons right?